# Deleted Jenkins Job Still Displays in GitHub Checks from GitHub Pull Request Plugin

Tags: jenkins, github, pull-request

My team uses the GitHub Pull Request Builder Jenkins plugin to run our tests on submitted PRs. We recently decided to delete a job, no longer running this suite of tests on PRs, as they were too time consuming.

However, on GitHub, this still job still shows up in the checks. The job has been completely deleted on Jenkins. It reports no result. Therefore, it always shows as "Pending."

This isn't just annoying to look at. It hurts our ability to quickly find PRs that were merged despite failing or pending tests.

With the job deleted, there's nothing that could still create this context tag. There's nothing we could change to eliminate it either. I, at first, suspected it was simply cached, but restarting the jenkins machine did not resolve it.

Where would this be set up and how can I go about removing it completely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Danielle,
I've faced the same problem one day.

1. You can just create another one job with the same triggering parameters and name. This job should do nothing and return SUCCESS.
2. Then you need to trigger this job by trigger phrase in each opened PR with Failed status.
3. Now you can delete this job.
   Done;)